# Is there a quark conservation law?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, quarks, interactions

The section on particle interactions in my revision guide says that only the weak interaction can change quark types, e.g. when a neutron changes to a proton the down quarks in the neutron are changed to up quarks.

So I was wondering: If it is only the weak interaction that can change quark type, that means that quarks can't be changed in a strong interaction. This means that the quark types have to balance on both sides of the equation in a strong interaction.

My real question: Is this therefore a valid conservation law for particle interactions?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

*Is there a quark conservation law?*

No. In proton-antiproton annihilation (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation#Proton-antiproton_annihilation)) the quarks are destroyed. See this section:

*"...when a proton encounters an antiproton, one of its constituent valence quarks may annihilate with an antiquark, while the remaining quarks and antiquarks will undergo rearrangement into a number of mesons (mostly pions and kaons), which will fly away from the annihilation point. The newly created mesons are unstable, and will decay in a series of reactions that ultimately produce nothing but gamma rays, electrons, positrons, and neutrinos."*

One can always talk about some interactions conserving quarks and/or certain quantum numbers, but IMHO it's going too far to start talking about quark conservation. Energy is conserved, matter isn't.

Comment: -1 This does not at all break the conservation of the number of quarks. An antiquark is considered equal to -1 quark.

Comment: @Martin van IJcken : So how many quarks are there in a meson? By your logic there are none.

Comment: Yes, a meson has net zero quarks. Just like how a hydrogen atom has net zero electric charge. We wouldn't say the electron positron anihilation violates charge conservation just because the number of electrically charged particles changes.

Comment: I know that the concept of the dirac sea is outdated, but it is sufficient for this situation: the antiquark could be seen not so much as a quark but as a hole in an endless sea of quarks, quark anti-quark anihilation has a quark fall into that hole, so the number of particles+holes decreases but the number of quarks remains constant.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, there are the quantum numbers [Charm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charm_%28quantum_number%29), [Strangeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangeness), [Topness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topness) and [Bottomness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottomness), which are conserved by strong and electromagnetic interactions, but not by weak interactions. Upness and Downness are simply the [Isospin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin), which is also preserved for strong interactions, when the quark masses can be neglected, which is usually a very good approximation as $m_u,m_d\ll \Lambda_{QCD}$. This $SU(2)$ isospin symmetry essentially breaks into $U(1)^2$, upness and downness, when the light quark masses become relevant.